# How to prevent a class from being inherited outside the library, while being inherited by public classes?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have the following classes in a library

```cs
public abstract class HiddenBaseClass
{
    //stuff
}
public abstract class ClassA : HiddenBaseClass
{
    //stuff
}
public abstract class ClassB : HiddenBaseClass
{
    //stuff
}
```

I want to prevent `HiddenBaseClass` from being inherited outside the library, but I do want `ClassA` and `ClassB` to be inherited.
I cannot make `HiddenBaseClass` an `internal class`, because that would mean `HiddenBaseClass` is less accessible than `ClassA` and `ClassB`.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: The scenario is very meaningless!

Comment: If you can inherit from `ClassA`, then you also inherit from `HiddenBaseClass`, so your requirements are in conflict. What problems does inheriting from `HiddenBaseClass` cause that you want to avoid?

Comment: [It seems that you have an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Because I do not want to have to copy & paste code between `ClassA` and `ClassB`, but I also have no reason to design `HiddenBaseClass` in such a way to support being inherited by the user.

Comment: While it's *possible* to design your code like this, as per my answer, I'd suggest using composition rather than inheritance where you can. We can't really tell whether that would help here, but it's something to consider.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contrary to the comments on the question, I believe this scenario *can* make sense, if `HiddenBaseClass` has aspects that you need to rely on being implemented internally (because you trust the internal implementations), but expose other abstract operations for external code to implement. It *may* not be an appropriate design for your use case, but it's not unreasonable.

One simple way to make it impossible to inherit from it directly outside the same library is to give it an internal constructor:

```cs
public abstract class HiddenBaseClass
{
    // Only classes in the same assembly can chain to this constructor.
    internal HiddenBaseClass() {}
}
```

So long as *all* the constructors in the class are internal (or private protected, or private) that will prevent classes in other assemblies from chaining *their* constructors to the base class constructors, thus preventing inheritance.

Comment: He can also define an interface and mark it as internal. In that case he can keep the abstract class as public.

Comment: @Transcendent: That wouldn't help with code reuse though. My answer *does* still keep the abstract class public - it's only the *constructor* that's internal.

Comment: Of course Sir Jon Skeet! :) I was only trying to suggest an alternative way. I don't think there's anyone out there daring to prove you (the Chuck Norris of Programming) wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments so politely pointed out, this isn't the best structure for this kind of scenario. In the end I'm going for an implementation like this:

```cs
internal sealed class HiddenBaseClass
{
    //stuff
}
public abstract class ClassA
{
    internal HiddenBaseClass { get; set; }
    //stuff that uses HiddenBaseClass
}
public abstract class ClassB
{
    internal HiddenBaseClass { get; set; }
    //more stuff
}
```

I apologise for asking the wrong questions yet again.

Comment: sealed classes cannot be inherited!

Comment: I'm not inheriting the sealed class am I? Edit: oh nevermind that was an oversight, I edited it.

Comment: You code does not compile, did you try to test it before posting the answer?

Comment: I accidentally inherited the class when I didn't mean to. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. What you are doing is actually called inversion of control.

Comment: Keep you code as in the question you posted, just add this `internal HiddenBaseClass() {}` (as Jon Skeet's answer)